# WildFly 10.0.0.CR5: equinoxbridgeservlet 404 Not Found

Tags: osgi, equinox, eclipse-rap, wildfly-9, wildfly-10

I have this servlet-mapping below. But whenever I access the url, it's always 404 Not Found.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>equinoxbridgeservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/console/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To give you an idea, I'm deploying an ear file with multiple war files. This also requires a security. After entering the correct credentials, I'm encountering 404 Not Found.

I'm not able to find anything from the log file as well. It's also working in jboss 5 but not in wildfly 9 or 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is a known "issue" or feature depends how you look at it.

To fix your problem, open standalone.xml locate undertow subsystem.
and add `disable-console-redirect="true"`

to `<host name="default-host" ...`

or in CLI execute:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host:write-attribute(name=disable-console-redirect, value=true)
```

or similar if you what to do that for different host/server

Comment: Hi @ctomc, I already added it in standalone-full-ha.xml (the one I'm using), but still, I'm getting the 404 error.

Comment: @xxx please add deploy log to your original question so we can see what is going on.

Comment: I have more than 6000 lines in my deploy log but I see no error in my deploy log. By the way, I think the issue is upon registering eclipse rap servlets. When debugging, I noticed that "/rap" is not being registered. This is upon comparing how jboss 5 and wildfly 10 projects work.

Comment: what if you just add log entries that contain WFLYUT and WFLYSRV message codes?

Comment: No error or warning found in log entries that contain WFLYUT and WFLYSRV.